# React app shortcuts implementation

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying different React shortcuts libs and have the same problem:
Shortcuts works only onfocused Component.
For example we have a product **List** **Component** and `onClick` we show that product **Description** **Component**, where we have another **Component** let it be **Favourite**.

```html
<List>
  <p onClick={this.showDescription}>Item 1</p>
  <p onClick={this.showDescription}>Item 2</p>
</List>
<Description>
  <h1> Item! </h1>
  <Favourite onClick={this.setFavourite}>
</Description>
```

So to set product as favourite I have to focus on Favourite Component before click hotkeys.

Is there any possibility to implement hotkeys to the whole app with nested unFocused components and unMounted also?